# Apply Worksheet_Change, to cell updated by Python code, to copy the updated cell data to another worksheet

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have the following script to fetch dynamically changing data in cell F60 on a worksheet. It is a stock price which constantly changes. This data is fetched by a Python code and is working.

I need to record this F60 data on another sheet within the same workbook every time it changes, without deleting the previously recorded data.

When I enter values manually in F60, I see all these values one by one on the destination sheet.
If the data is updated automatically (by Python code), I see the time stamp and not the data.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F60")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim x
        Dim NR As Long
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            x = Target.Value

            On Error Resume Next
            With Sheets("Sheet2")
                NR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

                .Range("A" & NR).Value = Now

                .Range("B" & NR).Value = x
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Worksheet_Change`-event is triggered *only* if data is modified within Excel (the program itself), either because a user typed or because a VBA code wrote something into one or more cells. It can't be triggered if you write it via Python. Python doesn't open (the Application) Excel and therefore no VBA environment is available. If Python writes the data, it also needs to write the data into your "history" sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Let me post my comment as answer:

The `Worksheet_Change`-event is triggered *only* if data is modified within Excel (the program itself), either because a user typed or because a VBA code wrote something into one or more cells.

It can't be triggered if you write it via Python (or any other program). Python doesn't open (the Application) Excel and therefore no VBA environment is available. VBA needs it's host program (in your case that's Excel) to run. If Python writes the data, it also needs to write the data into your "history" sheet.

Think of it vice versa: You have a text file (or any other file). If you write something into this file using Excel/VBA, you can't expect that a piece of Python code runs automatically and does something with the data.